# Android - issue with facebook logout

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, logout, access-token

Ive got an android app, it connect with facebook and ask for "offline access", so the access token should be always the same, but then I logout (facebook.logout()) and login again facebook is giving me a new access token.
How I can stop it?

Comment: Don't log out? When logging out you basically say that you explicity want to terminate this session (=make the token invalid). This means you will get a new token in the future. Just close your app and reuse the stored token next time.

Comment: ok, but when I dont logout and later click the to login again its automatically login me with default use and dont display a webview with facebook login (I pressed before to "not remember" my login and pass)

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. I just override the original facebook.logout function and change the facebook.authorize.

    public void logingOut(Context context)
    {
     Util.clearCookies(context);
     setAccessToken(null);
        setAccessExpires(0);
    }

and: facebook.authorize(this, perms,-1,new DialogListener()...